# circuitikz: rotate labels 90° and place on both sides

Tags: labels, circuitikz, rotating

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V, v=$10V$,invert] (0,6) -- (2,6)
    to[R, l_={$ \SI{100}{\kilo\ohm}$},] (2,3)
    to[R, l_={$ \SI{100}{\kilo\ohm}$}] (2,0) 
    -- (0,0);
    \draw (4,3) to [R, l={$R_{\text{probe}}=1$M$\Omega$}] (4,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[-Latex] (2,3) -- (5,3);
    \node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
    \node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{out}}$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to rotate the labels for the resistors 90° and for the `1$M$\Omega$` --> I'd like place this on the right side and the `R_{probe}` on the left side (so both 90°) rotated.

I tried:

```
\draw (4,3) to [R, l_={\rotatebox{90}{$R_{\text{probe}}=1$M$\Omega$}}] (4,0) -- (2,0);
```

but with this it's not centered
[image: original]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible "pure" `circuitikz` solution (without adding separate nodes for the labels) is this.

I had to change the direction in which the components are drawn because the labels under the `rotate` regime follow that direction when they are vertical.

For the "both side", I used a `l`abel and an `a`nnotation together.

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{label/align=rotate}
    \draw (2,0)
    to[R, l=\qty{100}{\kohm}] (2,3)
    to[R, l=\qty{100}{\kohm}] (2,6)  -- (0,6)
    to[V, v<=$10V$] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw (2,0) -- (4,0)
    to [R, l=$R_{\text{probe}}$, a=\qty{1}{\Mohm}] (4,3);
    \draw[-Latex] (2,3) -- (5,3);
    \node[circ] at (4,3) {};
    \node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{out}}$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Option `label/align=rotate`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[V, v=$10V$,invert] (0,6) -- (2,6)
    to[R, l_={$ \SI{100}{\kilo\ohm}$},] (2,3)
    to[R, l_={$ \SI{100}{\kilo\ohm}$}] (2,0) 
    -- (0,0);
    \draw (4,3) to [R, l={$R_{\text{probe}}=1$M$\Omega$}, label/align=rotate] (4,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[-Latex] (2,3) -- (5,3);
    \node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
    \node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{out}}$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use a global `\ctikzset{label/align=rotate}` to have all the labels rotating along the component. Section 5.1.3, "labels and annotation orientation". (+1!)

Comment: @Rmano You're great!!! Thankssssssssss.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation of the package siunitx, the command `\SI` is not recommended. Instead, use `\qty`.

The key `name` is used. Then the text is placed with a `\node` with the option `rotate=90` using the previously given name.

Furthermore, `$10V$` is replaced by `\qty{10}{\volt}` and `$1$M$\Omega$` by `\qty{1}{\mega\ohm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[V,v=\qty{10}{\volt}] (0,6)--(2,6) to[R,name=A] (2,3) to[R,name=B] (2,0)--(0,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (A.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\node[above,rotate=90] at (B.south) {\qty{100}{\kilo\ohm}};
\draw (4,3) to[R,name=C] (4,0)--(2,0);
\node[above,rotate=90] at (C.south) {$R_{\text{probe}}$};
\node[below,rotate=90] at (C.north) {\qty{1}{\mega\ohm}};
\draw[-Latex] (2,3)--(5,3);
\node[circ] at (4,3) {}; % Default label (you can customize it)
\node[above right] at (4,3) {$V_{\text{out}}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but it's a pity to add separate nodes when `circuitikz` has the possibility to align the labels automatically... see the manual, section 5.1.3, "label and annotation orientation".